# PHP loop is not throwing the correct link

Tags: php, html

for my issue i'll try to be as brief as possible

what am trying to do is reference a page with a specific id in the HTML anchor link with PHP as the below

```
<body>
<?php  $linkName = "Second Page"; ?>
<?php $id = 5; ?>

<a href="secondPage.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $linkName?></a><br>
```

and it works fine

now what am trying to do is to make the $id part more dynamic by making looping the number from 1 to 10 and also providing 10 links

the code is

```
</head>
<body>
    <?php  $linkName = "Second Page"; ?>
    <?php $id = 5; ?>

    <?php  
        for ($i=0; $i < 10 ; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='secondPage.php?id=<?php echo $i;?'>Link1</a>";
        };

    ?>
</body>
```

however what i did notice as the below images indicates when i hover on the links i noticed that i refer to a strange link

[image: Strange Link]

and when i cliched on it it takes me to the following link with an id that i did not want as below

```
http://localhost/PHP_Course/secondPage.php?id=%3C?php%20echo%201;?
```

i tried researching the subject and i tried escaping the quotation but it does not seem to resolve the problem

Any help please ??

Comment: You need to go learn some syntax basics. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing, http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: This with php's error reporting, would have clearly thrown you a parse error.

Comment: @CBroe thank i read through out the article and it really helped

Comment: @Fred-ii- thank you fred i'll check more about the error reporting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<?php` and `?>` tags indicate to the PHP preprocessor that anything inside them is code and needs to be parsed, everything outside is just text PHP doesn't touch.

Inside the `<?php` tag, `"<?php"` string has no special meaning, so is printed. You do not need to open and close tags all the time, try this:

```
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $linkName = "Second Page";
        $id = 5;

        for ($i = 0; $i < 10 ; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='secondPage.php?id=$i;'>Link1</a>";
        };
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you , it really slipped my eye's but thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You're echoing a string in PHP, and using `<?php...` inside that string.

Solution:

```
echo "<a href='secondPage.php?id=" . $i . "'>Link1</a>";
```

`id=$i` will also work, because you can include variables directly in double-quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

You're echoing the PHP code itself as a string.  You don't need to put PHP code *inside of* PHP code.  Just concatenate the values you want to echo:

```
echo '<a href="secondPage.php?id=' . $i . '">Link1</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

because you already started an echo statement so you don't need to add another PHP starting and ending tags. just check my code below and try it.

```
<?php  
           for ($i=0; $i < 10 ; $i++) { 
             echo "<a href='secondPage.php?id=".$i."'>Link1</a>";
    } ;

?>
```